# Why were June Moon and Flag in the subway?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad-2016

Partway through the film June Moon and Flag are setting a trap in the subway tunnel, until

> June Moon turns into enchantress, and steals/releases her brother,

Setting up there rest of the film. Why were they there in the first place?

Comment: I'm expecting this to be something blindingly obvious that I missed

Comment: If so, I missed it too. This movie had good points, but jeez, the writing was all kinds of horrible.

Comment: Could someone help me improve the question, by explaining the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

You have the order of events slightly wrong. The Enchantress read the file and learned of the location of her brother's canopic jar.

[image]

She broke into the Black Ops facility in Midway City and took possession of the jar.

[image]

Having removed the jar from the facility, she teleported to the nearest heavily inhabited area (Midway City Subway Terminus) where she knocked out a man in the bathroom, broke open the jar and allowed her brother to inhabit him.

[image]

After the Enchantress' brother started causing havoc, the military sent in a special ops team consisting of Flag, The Enchantress and several other nobodies. In the film we're just told

> "she bolted".

In the film's [official novelisation](http://titanbooks.com/suicide-squad-the-official-movie-novelization-8758/), it's made clear that she tried to *kill* Flag.

> In an instant June was gone, only to be replaced by the witch. Flag hesitated a moment to remind himself that this person—the thing he was holding—was not the woman he loved. That only through a bizarre twist of fate or magic or something inexplicable, they were sharing the same space and time.
>   He showed her the bomb and pointed to a button on the detonator.
>   “Once you put it in place, just push this button and drop it. It’s set to explode in two seconds. That should give you time enough to poof your way out of there.”
>   Enchantress smiled at Flag, not wanting to let him go.
>   “Darling,” she said, “I’d like to show you the world.”
>   “Seen it. Not impressed,” he said, calibrating the bomb’s timing mechanism.   “Okay. It’s ready. You can take it.”
>   Enchantress only laughed. She leaned in, gave him a kiss, pressed the button then disappeared in an instant…
>   …leaving Flag holding the armed bomb.
>   Two seconds.
>   That was all he needed.

[image]

Either way, **the reason Flag and the others were in the tunnel was ostensibly to kill the Enchantress' brother who was directly above them.**

Comment: To add to your great answer:
An important plot device, the demolition bomb, was brought by Flag and June to kill the brother from right beaneath his location. The plan stays the same with the team afterwards planning to kill the brother with the payload from beneath.

Answer (score 1):

Enchantress 's brother was already loose, and in that subway. They were sent to respond to that threat.

Comment: I'm confident I saw the doll for the brother intact which was the first thing enchantress stole when she transformed. Only afterwards did she release the spirit into a man in a restroom.